# when directive in jenkins pipeline shared library is not executed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, declarative

I setup a jenkins shared library in a git repo and configured it in my Jenkins according to [this page](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/10/02/pipeline-templates-with-shared-libraries/).

All the steps are fine, except `when` directive is not getting executed. I have a condition like below in my shared library which is ignored even when I return true along with `not`

```
when {
    not {
        expression {
           return true
        }
    }
}
```

The above condition should not execute the stage, but irrespective of what I used in the condition, the stage is getting executed.

Is `when` supported if given in the shared library for Jenkins pipeline declarative syntax?

Comment: the full declarative syntax is not supported until Pipeline Declarative plugin 1.2. I don't know if this will solve this, but if you can upgrade, try that first.